React Chrome Extension - value from Storage isn't shown in Component
I have a problem that one of my input fields isn't showing the value from the Storage that I saved beforehand with a context menu option. Any ideas? :)
I oriented myself on a chrome extension tutorial that I saw on Udemy. Unfortunately, I can't figure it out on my own and searching on the internet also wasn't very successful. :)
Storage.ts
export interface LocalStorage {
  shopURL?: string;
  naviID?: string;
}

export type LocalStorageKeys = keyof LocalStorage;

export function setStoredShopURL(shopURL: string): Promise<void> {
  const values: LocalStorage = {
    shopURL,
  };
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.storage.local.set({ values }, () => {
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

export function getStoredShopURL(): Promise<string> {
  const keys: LocalStorageKeys[] = ["shopURL"];
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.storage.local.get(keys, (res: LocalStorage) =>
      resolve(res.shopURL ?? "")
    );
  });
}

export function setStoredNaviID(naviID: string): Promise<void> {
  console.log(`naviID inside setStoredNaviID: ${naviID}`);
  const values: LocalStorage = {
    naviID,
  };
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.storage.local.set({ values }, () => {
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

export function getStoredNaviID(): Promise<string> {
  const keys: LocalStorageKeys[] = ["naviID"];
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.storage.local.get(keys, (res: LocalStorage) =>
      resolve(res.naviID ?? "")
    );
  });
}

popux.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import ClearIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Clear";
import FormHelperText from "@mui/material/FormHelperText";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./popup.css";
import { getCurrentTab } from "../background/background";
import { correctUserUrlInput } from "../utils/helperFunctions";
import { getStoredNaviID } from "../utils/storage";

function App() {
  const [shopURL, setShopURL] = useState("");
  const [naviID, setNaviID] = useState("");

  const handleClickDeleteUserInput = () => {
    setShopURL("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentTab().then((tab) => {
      const shortenedURL = correctUserUrlInput(tab.url);
      console.log(shortenedURL);
      setShopURL(shortenedURL);
    });
    getStoredNaviID().then((naviID) => {
      console.log(naviID);
      setNaviID(naviID);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="h4">React URL Picker</Typography>
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined" margin="normal">
          <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-url">Shop URL</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            id="outlined-adornment-url"
            type="text"
            value={shopURL}
            onChange={(event) => setShopURL(event.target.value)}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="delete user input"
                  onClick={handleClickDeleteUserInput}
                  edge="end"
                >
                  <ClearIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
            label="url"
          />
          <FormHelperText id="my-helper-text-url">
            Ihr müsst euch auf einer Shopseite befinden, damit diese automatisch
            ausgelesen wird.
          </FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined" margin="normal">
          <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-naviID">Navi-ID</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            id="outlined-naviID"
            type="text"
            value={naviID}
            onChange={(event) => setNaviID(event.target.value)}
            label="naviID"
          />
          <FormHelperText id="my-helper-text-naviID">
            Navi-ID der aktuellen Seite
          </FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

const container = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(container);
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);

import { getNaviID } from "../utils/helperFunctions";
import { setStoredNaviID } from "../utils/storage";

export async function getCurrentTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  return tab;
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "NaviID speichern",
    id: "saveNaviId",
  });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((clickData) => {
  if (clickData.menuItemId == "saveNaviId") {
    console.log("CLICK!");
    getCurrentTab().then((tab) => {
      console.log(tab.url);
      const naviID = getNaviID(tab.url);
      console.log(naviID);
      setStoredNaviID(naviID[0]);
    });
  }
});

manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "React URL Picker",
  "description": "React URL Picker for the Shopline Content Team",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "cntnt.png",
    "48": "cntnt.png",
    "128": "cntnt.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "React URL Picker",
    "default_icon": "cntnt.png"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "activeTab", "contextMenus"]
}

Thank you so much! :) Please also let me know if you need more code.

Inspect the storage interactively to see what's actually stored, your setStoredNaviID seems conceptually wrong. P.S. There's no need to explicitly promisify chrome API, it already returns a Promise. No need for getCurrentTab because onClicked already provides this info in its second parameter tab.

Hi woxxom! :) Thank you so much for your quick reply! I will try to fix these things. :)
